# Is it wrong to multiply the average number of occurences for a single period by the desired number of periods, to get an overall average?

Tags: mean, poisson-distribution

I'm working on a stats problem and I want to know if this is bad practice. (If it's reasonable, it'll save me a ton of time coding a different solution.)

During a day, an average of 3 events occur. If I want to know the average number of events in some number of days (for a Poisson distribution) can I just multiply the average number of occurrences by the desired number of days to get an overall average? The events are independent.

So, for two days the average number of occurrences is 6, for three days it's 9 etc.

Comment: In theory, yes, by linearity of the mean, the mean number of events in n days is equal to n times the mean number of events per day. But in practice, this raises a lot of questions. If you measure the number of events on one specific day, are you really measuring the mean number of events per day? Also, if you make an error `epsilon` in your one-day-measure, then multiply that by n, you know have an error `n * epsilon`.

Comment: Relatedly, paramedics are expected to measure heart rate and ventilation rate by counting the number of heart beats and number of breath intakes over one minute. They are explicitly forbidden from measuring those number over 30 seconds then multiplying by 2.

Comment: If you do this you're making an assumption that your Poisson process is homogeneous, i.e., that all days are similar and there aren't any rush hours or dead periods.  This is not a good assumption for restaurants, retail industries, emergency rooms, seasonal activities (such as swimming or recreational boating accidents), etc.  Even if you're willing to assume homogeneity, the resulting estimator may be unbiased but have too much variance to be useful - its variance will be inflated by the square of the multiplier.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You're interested in the mean, that is, the expected number of events over $n$ days.

You can model the number of events on day $i$ with a random variable $X_i$ ($i=1,2,\ldots, n$).

So, the number of events in the period of $n$ days is:
$$
\sum_{i=1}^{n} X_i
$$

The expected value of the sum is the sum of expected values:
$$
E\left[ \sum_{i=1}^{n} X_i \right] = \sum_{i=1}^{n} E[X_i]
$$
regardless of the distributions that those variables follow.

So, if all the days have the same expected value (say $\mu$), then, yes, the expected value over $n$ days will be $n\cdot \mu$.

Answer (score 5):

Adding to the answer by @Milos, you’re assuming that the average number of events per day follows Poisson distribution. We [know that](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_distribution) for independent variables

$$
X_i \sim \mathsf{Poisson}\left(\lambda_i\right)
$$

the distribution of their sum is

$$
\sum_{i=1}^n X_i \sim \mathsf{Poisson}\left(\sum_{i=1}^n \lambda_i\right)
$$

So if you can assume that the variables are independent and identically distributed, you can just multiply daily average by the number of days.